# Populate huge data from sql database to android ui

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, android-activity, android-sqlite

If I want to show thousands of rows and column to display in the android UI in a tabular format, what is the best way to do it ? Should I show it in a single shot on the activity. Can you please suggest any optimization?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just use a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, no need for any paginations, chunks etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can load thousand of rows from SQLITE within less than a second but loading huge data from database at once is not good practice. This will waste large amount of memory load data in chunks checkout below link i hope this will help you.

[Lazy data Loading](http://www.dmytrodanylyk.com/pages/blog/lazy-data-loading.html)

Answer (score 1):

For such huge set of data, it is much better to use [pagination or infinite scroll, lazy load](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/infinite-scrolling-lets-get-to-the-bottom-of-this/%20%22pagination%20or%20infinite%20scroll)  instead to not overwhelm the user with the whole set of results, each one has it good and bad area, it depends on your content and how to show it, also check https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36394/when-is-it-better-to-paginate-and-not-to-paginate for comparison

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler approach will be using Reclycler view, it does lazy loading for you.

http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

@Manjunath Rao it's just my view instead of displaying the complete set of data what you can do is display the record that you want by using the primary key....by this way not only can you view the records but, you can just view what you want and save time and the space occupied by the db...hope this is helpful to you....